# Texture Mask paints mesh with a grid instead of random

Tags: texture-painting

[image]
So I changed the Mask Mapping from Tiled to Random, added a bit of Jitter, and when I click to paint on my mesh, after a while it starts to look like it's following a grid. Is there a way to make it look like there is no grid at all, and it follows a random order?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer with a little tinkering. Checking Rake or Random or both removes the grid it keeps locking onto.

[image]

If anyone knows why or how this works, comment.